# How do you unmute someone in chat?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Sometimes in global chat, I accidentally click the "Mute" button when trying to visit them, but then I never see their name ever again. I still want to talk to them and want to unmute but there seems to be no option to do so since the name is gone.

So is there any way at all to unmute a player in global chat?

Answer (score 3):

> "As of the July 29, 2013 update, there is now an option to mute a
>   selected player from the global chat window. This will remove their
>   messages from your chat window but will not affect those of other
>   players. As of yet, there is no way to unmute a player that you have
>   previously muted. When you leave the chatroom, any players you muted
>   will be unmuted."

I have not found any indication of this changing in any of the more recent patch notes.

[source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Global/Clan_Chatrooms)

Comment: The only problem with this... Is getting back into the same chatroom.

Comment: @aytimothy yea, basically if you muted someone and you dont know which clan they are from, or have contact outside of the game, you most likely wont ever find them again